# How do I write code in SQL for following example

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, BOQ and DPR

**Table : BOQ**

```
ID | Buidling| Activity |Plan_Start_Date|Actual_Start_Date
1  |A-1      |Shuttering|02-02-2019     |15-02-2019
2  |A-2      |Shuttering|13-02-2019     |13-02-2019
```

**Table : DPR**

```
ID | Buidling| Activity |Date          |
1  |A-1      |Shuttering|15-02-2019    |
```

I need to write an expression for column `Actual_Start_Date` such that when `Building` and `Activity` columns are matched in both tables then it should display the date in DPR table as `Actual_Start_Date` (in above case 15-02-2019 is `Actual_Start_Date` of id 1 in BOQ as the table and activity columns are matched).
If there is no matching value then `Actual_Start_Date` should show `Plan_start_Date` as in ID 2 of BOQ

Comment: Your sample data contain only 2 rows. If there is no matching value there maybe many non matching rows in table BOQ. From which row should the column be updated?

Comment: If repeated value at first in list gets updated

Comment: Repeated value of what column?You set the match on 2 columns. If there is no match on both columns there is no first or next or last.

Comment: If both coloumns are not matched or none of the coloumns are matched then Actual_Start_Date should be same as corresponding Plan_Start_Date in BOQ

Comment: *same as corresponding Plan_Start_Date in BOQ* from which row of BOQ? If the table BOQ has 100 rows and there are 50 non matching rows from which row should the value update the rows of the other table?

Answer (score 0):

You want a `left join`:

```
select . . .,  -- whatever other columns you want
       coalesce(dpr.date, boq.actual_start_date) as actual_start_date
from boq left join
     dpr
     on boq.building = dpr.building and
        boq.activity = dpr.activity;
```

You can easily turn this into an `update`:

```
update boq join
       dpr
       on boq.building = dpr.building and
          boq.activity = dpr.activity
    set boq.actual_start_date = coalesce(dpr.date, boq.actual_start_date) ;
```

Comment: HI i tried it and it is working but it is creating a new table for the results but i need the reults to be updated in boq table.I need it as an expression